# Android NFC: Exception "transceive failed" when using transceive()

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to communicate between a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a smartcard that supports `NfcA` and `IsoDep` (Mifare DESFire EV1). To do this, I enabled forgeground dispatch and started a task when a tag is discovered. The code in the task looks like this:

```
IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);

byte[] selectCommand = {
        (byte)0x00, // CLA
        (byte)0xA4, // INS
        (byte)0x04, // P1
        (byte)0x00, // P2
        (byte)0x0A, // LC
        (byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x08,(byte)0x09,(byte)0xFF, // AID
        (byte)0x7F  // LE
};

try {
    isoDep.connect();
    byte[] response = isoDep.transceive(selectCommand);
    String result = bytesToString(response);
    isoDep.close();
    return result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The transceive method throws this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
```

All other methods of `IsoDep` (like `getTimeout()`) can be executed without error. Increasing the timeout doesn't change the behaviour. The applet with the AID in the select command is present on the card. I also tried to use the `NfcA` class. But then I get the exception "tag is lost".

Could the Galaxy S3 be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to set _Le=0x00_?

Comment: Does `00 A4 04 00 07 D2 76 00 00 85 01 01 00` command APDU work?

Comment: It's the same exception for both your suggestions.

Comment: And `905A00000300000000`?

Comment: I've worked with DESFire EV1 in ISO mode on S3 without problems. Could you check your card with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite)?

Comment: I tried to scan the card with this app on two phones (including the s3), on both i get the message "The tag was unexpectedly removed. Analysis may be incomplete or wrong."

Comment: That is strange, is your card OK? Do you have any other card to check?

Comment: I haven't had any problems with the card so far. However, i worked mainly with a card reader until now. I don't have any other card to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the same app on another phone and it worked without any problems. The Galaxy S3 is indeed the problem.