# Work around/quick fix for transceive failed error?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

This question has been asked couple of times but it still **doesn't have a clear answer.** According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262197/transceive-failed-on-galaxy-s3-with-a-nfc-b-card) question, the reason is because of transceive timeout. Some developers filed an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37882) about this but I don't see any clear solution on the thread.

I'm trying to write in NTAG216 using MifareUltralight class. I'm using `writePage` method, and that's where the error occurs.

This is part of the error report:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Transceive failed at     
android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52) 
at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:173)
```

What I have tried so far:

1. increase timeout
2. manually write using transceive with write command

Test devices where writing to tag **works**:

1. Samsung galaxy note 3(SM-N900L). android version 4.3
2. Some local manufacturer's phone. android version 4.4.2

Test devices where writing to tag **doesn't work**:

1. Samsung galaxy note 2(GT-N7100). android version 4.4.2
2. Some local manufacturer's phone. android version 4.2
3. [Famoco](http://www.famoco.com/?gclid=CMSu6ub8mcoCFYKWvAodlxkOtA) phone. android version 4.4.2

As you can see, one 4.4.2 version works, and the other one doesn't work. (Note that I have password in the tag and I am successfully authenticating)

What I know so far is that this is a [hardware issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149704/android-nfc-exception-transceive-failed-when-using-transceive). But I once used `writeNdefMessage` method and those devices can write to the tag. I just switched to tranceive method because I'm password protecting the tag.

According to [this thread's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432796/android-nfc-issue-with-apdu-commands), it might be because the phone's nfc capacity couldn't handle the tag's power requirement. But as I mentioned before, I was using `writeNdefMessage` and it was working, so power requirement is out of the question.

Note: Reading contents of tag works using read command `(byte) 48` even though writing `(byte) 162` gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that **the phone is too slow**. So to solve the problem, you have to refactor your code such that it will be faster.

What I did was create several threads for parallel computing.

Comment: Thanks to this i figured out that if we debug line by line we can get a Transceive error, hence debugging it not recommended